# Neighborhood data for Canada

Tags: canada

I am looking for Canada Locality/neighborhood data but did not get any useful links. Anybody know about a good Locality/neighborhood data for Canada??

Comment: **What** data? Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and update your question

Comment: https://open.canada.ca/en/maps/open-data-canada?

Comment: What levels of localities are you interested in? There are a lot of different subregions of data available through the Canada Census Boundary Files (http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm), Otherwise, provincial governments may have finer scale or different subregional units (e.g. Neighbourhoods in Quebec CIty: https://www.donneesquebec.ca/recherche/fr/dataset/vque_56).

Answer (score 1):

Not comprehensive, but ESRI's open data hub [has some Canadian neighborhood data](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=canada%20neighborhoods&t=content&start=1&sortOrder=desc&sortField=relevance).
Unfortunately, Zillow doesn't offer neighborhood data in Canada like in the US, and also Code for America's *Click My 'Hood* app doesn't actually have neighborhood data, just Canadian provinces.